# Is it possible to run the Linux binaries in WIndows using CygWin?

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, gfortran, binaries

I have some gfortran linux binaries, which I have to execute in windows. I have tried to create a *.exe, by making the MakeFile for windows. However, I have some issues with recompiling the code in windows and also as I'm new to fortran, it is taking time. So I have did research, if we can run the linux binaries in windows without compiling. I have found many sources, which mention CygWin (also a source from Stackoverflow [How to convert a linux executable file (binary) to windows exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396103/how-to-convert-a-linux-executable-file-binary-to-windows-exe-file)). I have tried to run the *.sh file using bash command, but it shows the following error

[image]

Do I have to recompile the code or can I run the linux binaries directly ?

Comment: Windows 10 has the Windows Subsystem for Linux, which theoretically allows you to run Linux binaries.  It's still in beta though.

Comment: Is your program from this site? http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xfoil/

Comment: @HarryJohnston thanks for your comment.

Comment: @roygvib No it is not from this site