# Converting a Linux C++ library to Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I have fallen in love with the capabilities of [Rheolef](https://www-ljk.imag.fr/membres/Pierre.Saramito/rheolef/), a C++ library for Finite Element Analysis that is available for Linux only. I am developing an application in Windows and was wondering if I can build Rheolef for Windows and use it in my application.

I read a few posts about Cygwin but my understanding is that it only mimics the Linux environment in a Windows settings. Also, I found [a technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14396337/1227860) that can compile a single source code for Windows.

Is there any tool or method that could make the entire Rheolef library for Windows from Linux?

Comment: Find which libraries it depends on. If all those are available in source form, or in binary form for Windows, try to build from source. Fix first problem, repeat. At some point either you give up or you succeed.

Comment: The very large number of dependencies that rheolef has means I think you are going to struggle. However cygwin would be the way to go I think.

Comment: The linux for windows subsystem is an even closer match to an actual *nix environment (as it runs ELF binaries directly).

Comment: Short answer: No.